# Can feedback be used on buildings?

Tags: starcraft-2

Can you feedback buildings: Nexus, Orbital center?

Comment: Feedback? As in destroy to get some resources back?

Comment: @Ivo Feedback as in the Templar ability to drain energy for damage. @Let_Me_Be I have no idea if it can be used on a building.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Feedback)<sup>*</sup> (and the fact that I just tried it), it can't.

> <sup>*</sup> Feedback is an offensive spell cast by the Protoss High Templar. It is cast on an enemy spell caster (**cannot be used on buildings**), depleting the target's energy pool and dealing one point of damage for each energy lost. Feedback can only be cast on units with energy.

Comment: you can use it on point defense drone though.

Comment: @StimTebow I would argue that a point defense drone is like a tank in seige mode.  Still a unit, but just can't move.